# How to loop through messages from mysql database and display them correctly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm building a chat program.

Every time a user sends a message it gets stored in a table called 'messages'. The table looks like this:
[image]

When a user disconnects, and later connects again, the old messages should be displayed the same way, as when they were send. 
In the image you can see that received messages are grey, and others are blue:
[image]

When a user connects, I am retrieving the old messages with this code:

```js
// Retrieve conversation
 client.on("retrieveConversation", function(data){
  var peopleName = data.result.conversation_receiver;
  var retrievedMessages = [];
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `message_key` = '" + data.result.conversation_key + "'", function(error, results, fields){
   if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
         } 
         else if (results) {
            console.log("Messages: ", results);
         } 
  });
  console.log("Retrieving conversation", peopleName);
  client.emit("addConversationForSelf", peopleName);
 });
```

And the result looks like this in the console:
[image]

How can I loop through the results and control which messages (from body) should emit to either: 1.`client.emit("newMessageToOthers", message);` or 2. `client.emit("ownMessage", message);` - Note that these two options control whether the messages are grey or blue.

Comment: Do you know userfrom_id at the time of looping to differentiate between 'ownMessage' and 'newMessageToOthers'?

Comment: Sorry @vabii, I dont understand your question?

Comment: The userfrom_id gets stored with the message. I have updated my questions with an image of how my message table looks.

Comment: To know whether the RowDataPacket belongs to you or any other user, you need to know your userFrom_id, right? I was asking if you have that info so that during loop, you can call one of the two above 'client.emit' calls. Let me know if my question is still not clear?

Comment: Yep. When a user sends a message, their id is added to each individual message.

Comment: wait.. you store the message text and data to a database? Could get very big, might seem like a big job to redo at first but in long run it might help out - you should check out $_SESSIONS.. but if it's a chat service (which it looks like) - maybe consider coding it in node.js + php?

Comment: At some point I'm probably gonna do it in node.js + php. However right now, it is kind of a test for me to do, so I have to stick to javascript. How would it be better to do in php?. All messages are stored in the database

Comment: @JonasSH. Yes, that is good but you also need your id when connecting. For above emample, you need Jay's userfrom_id so once you loop, you can compare that user id with individual RowDataPacket and call client.emit("ownMessage", message).

Comment: Okay. Could you maybe give an example of how the loop would look like? I'm still a newbie :-)

Comment: @JonasSH, added a example for simple loop, I trimmed the result body for the example. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var results = [{body: 'Hi', userfrom_id: 'abc'}, {body: 'Hi', userfrom_id: 'xyz'}, {body: 'Hi', userfrom_id: 'abc'}]; //this is your result from database
var currUser_id = 'abc'; //this is current user

//loop
results.forEach(function(packet){if(packet.userfrom_id == currUser_id){console.log('my packet');}else{console.log('other user packet')}});
```